# Difference between 忘 and 忘记

Tags: grammar, word-choice

So is there any differences between 忘 and 忘记？They both mean to forget but do they have any other differences in terms of usage, location within a sentence, etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please read [Result complement](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Result_complement)

Also [了](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/460/) :  *'aspect marker' indicating completed action*

'忘' (forget) as a verb cannot be used without a result complement or aspect marker

Example:

> '忘掉'
>
> 掉 is the result complement of 忘.
>
> It describes the result of forget is the object is 'forgot away' (from one's mind)
>
> You cannot remove the result complement '掉' from '(忘掉)自己的手電號碼' and write '(忘)自己的手電號碼'

~

> '忘了'
>
> 了 is a aspect marker that indicates 'completion of an action'
>
> You cannot remove the aspect marker '了' from '(忘了)自己的手電號碼' and write '(忘)自己的手電號碼'

~~~~~~~~~

- '忘' = 'forget'
- '记' = 'remember/ recollect'
- '**忘记**' (forget to remember) = '**to forget**'

'忘记' is a compound word verb

It can be used with or without a result complement or aspect marker

Example:

忘记自己的手電號碼 = forget one's own cell-phone number

忘记(掉)自己的手電號碼 = forget one's own cell-phone number (away)

(忘记了)自己的手電號碼 = (forgotten) one's own cell-phone number

*Terms like '忘本'，'忘情' that directly apply the verb 忘 before a noun, are in effect, compound words  as in "做人**忘本**" (being **ungrateful**), **忘情**演出 (**passionately** perform).*

*The other cases of 忘 directly apply before a noun are 1. 'in idiomatic form',  like "見利忘義" 2. 'with an adverb',  like 難忘, 不忘, 未忘, and they are all literary terms*

Answer (score 3):

see dictionaries (esp. examples): 忘记    forget disremember 忘记;忽略 lose sight of 
忘:忘却。忘怀。忘我。忘情。忘乎所以, showing **忘** only occurs in a limited number of fixed (time-honored) expressions, including 成语。
**忘记 explained**: 合成词  of type B
（see e.g. 实用汉语语法，词的构成，３。２。合成词的构造方式 ３。２。１。**联合式**合成词。。。B：两个语素的原义发生了变化：有的产生了新义，有的只保留部分原义。如＂东西、开关、矛盾、买卖、**忘记**＂。Also see baike.baidu,**联合型（并列型）**：举例：3.
两词根意结合后，只有一个词根的意项在起主要作用。
例如：国家 人物 **忘记** 没有 质量